# page is getting redirected without setting value in state and in localstorage in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, local-storage, react-cookie

```
const [userid, setUserId] = useState()
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/Signin', { email, password })
        .then(result => {
            if (result.data.message === "Successfully Login") {
                setUserId(((result.data.ID).toString()))
                if(userid === result.data.ID){
                    navigate('/')
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('UserID' , userid)
},[])
```

Here whats happening is there is an sign in form which collects data and on click of button that details are being checked in mongoose and from there i am getting an id from result so now i want to store that id in localstorage then i want to redirect to the home page which is navigate('/').

But here page is being redirected without the data is set into a localstorage .

can anyone help me with this. i am learning react so dont have much idea about it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try setting the localStorage after the successful login message before you navigate:

```
 localStorage.setItem('UserID', result.data.ID);  navigate('/'); 
```

Comment: Hey That worked but the localstorage data wont be removed until i clear it right?

Comment: yes the data will persist unless removed. you can remove it by adding an expiration time `localStorage.setItem('UserID', result.data.ID, {expires: 1});` that expires in 1 day, or you can remove it when the component unmounts using a useEffect that returns `localStorage.removeItem('UserID'); ` or you can put that removeItem line in a function then call it where you want.

Comment: Hey once again thank you so much for helping me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is likely due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. When you call localStorage.setItem('UserID', userId), it's executed immediately after setting userid using setUserId, but setUserId is an asynchronous function, and the value of userid might not be updated by the time localStorage.setItem is called.

To fix this, you should use the useEffect hook to watch for changes to **userId** and then set the item in localStorage.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/Signin', { email, password })
        .then(result => {
            if (result.data.message === "Successfully Login") {
                const userIdString = (result.data.ID).toString();
                setUserId(userIdString);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (userId) {
        localStorage.setItem('UserID', userId);
        navigate('/');
    }
}, [userId]);
```

In this code, I've added a dependency array **[**userId**]** to the useEffect, so it only runs when userid changes. When userid is updated after a successful login, the useEffect will set the UserID in localStorage and then trigger the navigation to the home page.